# MS ACCESS read uncommitted

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I try to read an uncommitted data in MS ACCESS to have a "preview" of the result :
I begin a session and change data in my database.
I open a Report with these data.
I rollback my changes.

The report must read uncommitted data, I try "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED" but acces say that "SET" is not a valid keyword.
I also try "WITH UR" and access say "syntax error"

Is there a solution to change the isolation level to uncommitted in the beginning of a query and change the isolation level to committed at the end ?

My VBA-Part code :

```
Dim Wrk As Workspace
Set Wrk = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Wrk.BeginTrans
'...
'All the database modifications
'...
DoCmd.close
DoCmd.OpenReport "Preview Form" 'Only reading
MsgBox "Printed !"
Wrk.Rollback
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute Transact-SQL against a JET database?

Answer (score 1):

Change your ODBC configuration:

```
1.- Control Panel --> Administrative Tools --> Data Sources (ODBC)
2.- Your DSN --> Configure --> Advanced Settings
3.- Set SQL_TXN_ISOLATION=1.
```

More info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525699(v=vs.90).aspx

Regards

Comment: Is there a solution to change it temporary in query or in VBA code ?
BTW I don't find the option, here is what i view as options : http://imgur.com/YTuamSa

Comment: You say me that is not possible to do that in Access ?